# Javascript - Function call will not enter function body

Tags: javascript

I have a function acting as a constructor that, when called, gets as far as the function definition in the debugger, but never to the function body.  Is there a common reason this may happen that I am overlooking?  Example code below:

myconstructor.js

```
function MyConstructor(optionalParam) { //this breakpoint gets hit
    var newobj = {}; //breakpoint never hit
    //code to check for null parameter
    //other code
};
```

main.js

```
var myConstructor = new MyConstructor();
```

There must be something I have overlooked, but I can't see what that is.  Neither firefox/firebug nor VS report errors or warnings.

Thanks!

Comment: Not sure as I don't use javascript but are you required to so send the 'optionalParam' to the constructor so use 'var myConstructor = new MyConstructor(optionalParam);'.

Comment: Does MyConstructor return anything?  Without a return value the variable myConstructor should end up being undefined.

Comment: Have you tried putting `console.log()` inside the function body?

Comment: Nothing looks wrong with that code. Is it an issue with the debugger itself? Vivin Paliath's suggestion about `console.log()` (or even an old fashioned `alert()`) might be instructive.

Comment: Because MyConstructor() is called using the 'new' keyword, it returns a new object containing everything declared using 'this.<property>' within the function body.

Tried console.log() inside the body.  It does not appear to be getting run.

Thanks for the ideas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your syntax looks correct, and it works inline. Did you make sure you closed all your script tags?

```
<script src="myconstructor.js" type="text/javascript">

<script type="text/javascript">
  var myConstructor = new MyConstructor();
</script>
```

Won't work. If that's not it, I got absolutely nothin'.

Comment: The tags were closed, but out of order (stupid mistake.)  Marked as answer since it was a script tag related problem.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Would the function not have to be inside a class for you to be able to instantiate it?

Comment: Javascript doesn't have classes

Comment: Nope, it is declared globally (or more accurately it is declared within 'window'.)  So the call could just as easily be var myConstructor = new window.MyConstructor().  Just as a sanity check, I do have other 'classes' defined in this same fashion (that work.)

Comment: Hmm I guess you're right, but I found this: http://www.webmonkey.com/2010/02/make_oop_classes_in_javascript/
Which is kinda what I meant (although it may not be the cause of the problem)

Comment: have you tried just putting an alert('test'); in there instead? just to check everything up to that point is working?